# Update Query woe - incorrect field is updated

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in Access and am trying to update a foreign key field (type is number) of one large facilities table with an imported table that is more current.

I've checked and doublechecked the Query and the **Field Row** and **Update To Row**s are both correct. The Field Row is being updated with data from an entirely different field that is text, not number.

Is there a known issue? I am stumped. I am not a programmer so am using the GUI and not the code.

Comment: Switch your query from Design View to SQL View.  Copy the SQL statement text and paste it into the question.  If it's a huge monster query, please make a simpler version which demonstrates the problem and show us the simple version.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to paste the code along with the question. I will do that next time.